# How do I add the Keychain sharing feature to my App ID?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, keychain

I am using Firebase to create a Login portal. I first connected an Apple account to Xcode which didn't have an iPhone or iPad connected to it and this error popped up. Now I have removed that account and added another one which has an iPhone connected to it but still the error pops up. How do I resolve it?[image]

Answer (score 0):

*It's a bit late, but if anyone else runs into this issue:*

I had the same issue. I was using `com.test.TestApp` as my bundle identifier (which in turn made it the KeychainGroup ID when activating).

Changing my bundle identifier under `Project > Targets > AppName > General > Identity > Bundle Identifier` to something more unique like `com.myLastName.TestApp` solved it for me. Be sure to also adjust the KeychainGroup identifier to match your newly changed bundle identifier.